# Docker Swarm and Windows nodes persistent storage

Tags: docker, docker-swarm, docker-for-windows

We have a `Docker Swarm cluster` with `Linux` and `Windows` nodes.

Currently we use `Docker version 19.03.1, build 74b1e89`.

On the Linux nodes, we use `NFS` storage but this seems not possible on the Windows nodes.

What we tried so far:

- Creating a [nfs volume](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/volume_create/#driver-specific-options) gives the error `options are not supported on this platform`
- Setup nfs share prior starting service gives the error `invalid volume specification … invalid mount config for type "bind" … source path does not exist ...`
- Using [SMB Global Mapping](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/windowscontainers/manage-containers/container-storage#smb-mounts) gives the error `The parameter is incorrect`

For the `SMB Global Mapping`, created the share for `V:`

```bsh
$secpasswd = ConvertTo-SecureString 'test' -AsPlainText -Force
$creds = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ("test", $secpasswd)
New-SmbGlobalMapping -RemotePath \\192.168.100.100\tmp -Credential $creds -LocalPath V:
```

And used the following `docker-compose`:

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  smb:
    image: mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore/iis:windowsservercore-1903
    volumes:
      - V:\poc:C:\inetpub\wwwroot
    ports:
      - 8080:80
    networks:
      - default

networks:
  default:
```

And this is the error message:

```
ERROR: for smb  Cannot start service smb: hcsshim::CreateComputeSystem f7d850c78830cb6c0933dc1b4d95035ace6e8d712fb37db24896311f52e2db90: The parameter is incorrect.
(extra info: {"SystemType":"Container","Name":"f7d850c78830cb6c0933dc1b4d95035ace6e8d712fb37db24896311f52e2db90","Owner":"docker","IgnoreFlushesDuringBoot":true,"LayerFolderPath":"C:\\ProgramData\\Docker\\windowsfilter\\f7d850c78830cb6c0933dc1b4d95035ace6e8d712fb37db24896311f52e2db90","Layers":[{"ID":"945ed3ff-4e7f-58e9-b88f-c87c850cc81e","Path":"C:\\ProgramData\\Docker\\windowsfilter\\a240ba3f3c05dab6080c1e01fd0b3692f1731247a77b8be965c81671631eb223"},{"ID":"a2b23cbc-2bc6-549a-a6d3-568f5aa1ba1e","Path":"C:\\ProgramData\\Docker\\windowsfilter\\19595266d37a2d38b4d19c3f5dcc91c1a52c64808d589df00f0a383edf1e317a"},{"ID":"73d26471-1e22-5d8a-b948-6f8effff0dcf","Path":"C:\\ProgramData\\Docker\\windowsfilter\\4e8597b8eb2ce54456d622e9ff82d5c0f52c8e137495f86f6adf8a0d4d692a7e"},{"ID":"ebe5a7a6-7821-5098-865b-75bc9cdca278","Path":"C:\\ProgramData\\Docker\\windowsfilter\\46e64689e93c40d6634b136c2242cfea6e253cf05f02838c4bfb57d10a999b91"},{"ID":"a64e3b2e-ccdd-5f5e-b342-99226d4c6991","Path":"C:\\ProgramData\\Docker\\windowsfilter\\b074eb9cfdf114ecaaf6a0104a710cdb3abc41f93f4dbd6161681df443c07188"}],"HostName":"f7d850c78830","MappedDirectories":[{"HostPath":"v:\\poc","ContainerPath":"c:\\inetpub\\wwwroot","ReadOnly":false,"BandwidthMaximum":0,"IOPSMaximum":0,"CreateInUtilityVM":false}],"HvPartition":true,"EndpointList":["60F1BA39-5E74-41A0-84C7-C0F76680E78F"],"HvRuntime":{"ImagePath":"C:\\ProgramData\\Docker\\windowsfilter\\46e64689e93c40d6634b136c2242cfea6e253cf05f02838c4bfb57d10a999b91\\UtilityVM"},"AllowUnqualifiedDNSQuery":true})
ERROR: Encountered errors while bringing up the project.
```

Does anyone have a solution on how to use persistent storage on a Windows node in a Docker Swarm cluster?

Comment: Did you enable SMB File sharing support in Windows Features ?

Comment: `SMB file sharing` is already enabled.

Comment: can you post the docker run command or the portion of the compose which you are using to mount the volume

Comment: @SoumenMukherjee  added the used command, docker-compose & error message to the initial thread.

Answer (score 0):

Before you run the powershell command as outlined in #3, you need to enable the SMB file sharing in Windows Feature.

[image: SMB Feature]

Once the feature is enabled, make sure the share the folder and add necessary security permissions.

This has to be followed by running the following commands

1. `$creds = Get-Credential`
2. `New-SmbGlobalMapping -RemotePath \\SERVER\SharePath $creds -LocalPath DRIVE:`